# Cannot pipe wget HTTP header for grep processing

Tags: linux, shell, grep, wget, embedded-linux

I am trying to get the integer value of a camera temp sensor through a wget request to a php page.
The camera has Busybox 1.13.3 with dash shell, so some common cmds (like curl) and mathematical POSIX functions are not present.
I don't want the HTTP header to be displayed in the terminal, but I want it to be processed (or just dumped) with the page retrieval.
I just want the number (in the case below 49) to be displayed in the shell.
This is the code I've written so far:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                          
wget -O- /mnt/0/t2 -q "http://127.0.0.1/i2c.php?width=8&bus=1&adr=0x4800"\ 
2>&1 \
| egrep -i "<data>" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

This is what is displayed in the console:

```
# ./tp2.sh                                                                                                              
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 - [07/Dec/2014:03:30:36 +0000] "GET /i2c.php?width=8&bus=1&adr=0x4800 HTTP/1.1" 200 188 "-" "Wget"  
49
```

I tried using `2> /dev/null` but it doesn't work either.

Then I tried just the wget portion of the code, in this order, to flush everything to /dev/null:
`wget -O- -q "http://127.0.0.1/i2c.php?width=8&bus=1&adr=0x4800" >/dev/null 2>&1` as explained [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial), but I am still getting the HTTP response on the console:
`127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 - [07/Dec/2014:14:13:24 +0000] "GET /i2c.php?width=8&bus=1&adr=0x4800 HTTP/1.1" 200 188 "-" "Wget"` .

How can I force the HTTP header to be hidden from the console output?

Comment: Have you considered piping to `tail -n1`?

Comment: By the way, you might want to remove the `sed` substitution to see the entire first output line. Maybe it'll become clear why or if that line gets grep-ed.

Comment: If I remove sed, I get the line `<data>49</data>` . The HTTP header seems to be treated as a debug message, so it's like an error output. I just can't send it to /dev/null .

Comment: Output is either in 1 (normal), or in 2 (error). So, if you catch both (either to a file or to null), in theory you should not have output. Sometimes, what looks as error output, is normal output. In the opening post, I don't see redirect of 1 ..

Comment: I tried just the wget portion of the code, in this order, to flush everything to /dev/null: `wget -O- -q "http://127.0.0.1/i2c.php?width=8&bus=1&adr=0x4800" >/dev/null 2>&1` as explained [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial), but I am still getting the HTTP response on the console: `127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 - [07/Dec/2014:14:13:24 +0000] "GET /i2c.php?width=8&bus=1&adr=0x4800 HTTP/1.1" 200 188 "-" "Wget" ` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests I was able to track down what was causing that message to be displayed.
The camera has **Lighttpd** installed, and in the *lighttp.conf* file found in */etc* there was a tiny option that had been changed by the camera manufacturer.
It is the access log, which tracks all http requests received by the web server.
This is the option now:

```
#### accesslog module
accesslog.filename          = "/var/log/lighttpd_access.log"
```

while I found it to be pointing to `/dev/console`.

Now I am correctly getting only the temp value.
Thanks a lot guys!